# PHP + JQuery Reload page when language switcher changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a few questions about the php JQuery language switch functions.
I would like to develop a function when the user changed the language (e.g english -> chinese). The website will reload the exiting page and add language code value to the url.

situation 1 :

before change language:
httpp://url
after change language:
httpp://url/zh-TW/

situation 2 :

before change language:
httpp://url/product/abc
after change language:
httpp://url/zh-TW/product/abc

Below is my exiting code. The language switch function is working but i don't know how to do the replace url. 
** the jquery part is reference from another website. Thank you so much

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> <?php echo $langName ; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a name="locale-option" about="" locale="en" id="locale_en">English</a></li>
        <li><a name="locale-option" about="" locale="zh-TW">繁體中文</a></li>
        <li><a name="locale-option" about="" locale="zh-CN" id="locale_zh">简体中文</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[name='locale-option']").click(function(f){
        f.preventDefault();
        var b=$(this).attr("locale");
        var d=$(this).attr("about");
        var c=window.location.href;
        if(d==1&&(b=="zh-CN"||b=="zh-TW")){
            tipsDialog(jsLocale.alert_title_error,jsLocale.activity_language_type);
            return
        } else {
            if(d==2&&b=="en"){
                tipsDialog(jsLocale.alert_title_error,jsLocale.activity_language_type);
                return
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/functions/lang_switcher.php?lang="+b+"&url="+c,
            success:function(e){
                window.location.replace(e.jumpURL);
            },
            error:function(e){

            }
        })
    });
});
```

php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

if(isSet($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $lang;
}   
    else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])){
        $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    }
    else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    }
    else {
        $lang = 'zh-TW';
    }

switch ($lang) {
    case 'en':
        $lang = 'en';
        $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
        $langName = 'English';
    break;

    case 'zh-CN':
        $lang = 'zh-CN';
        $lang_file = 'lang.zh-CN.php';
        $langName = '简体中文';
    break;

    case 'zh-TW':
        $lang = 'zh-TW';
        $lang_file = 'lang.zh-TW.php';
        $langName = '繁體中文';
    break;

    default:
        $lang = 'zh-TW';
        $lang_file = 'lang.zh-TW.php';
        $langName = '繁體中文';
}

include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file ;
```

Comment: Try to use `window.location.href = "http://example.com"; return false;` over the `window.location.replace("");` method, returning false helps to make the function "*jump out*"

Comment: Or looking at your code, you are using the response data as a URL, does this data contain just that or is it something more? Try to print it or log it (with and without `jumpURL` on it and see what the data returned is. As success gets **everything** printed to the screen as the user would see it, you could have HTML tags in there that is ruining the `location.replace` call and messing it up

Comment: Thank you for your sugguestion.I am a beginner in web development.^^ I reference from this website http://www.klook.com/. How to build the language switch function like this. Can you give me some idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just include at the end of your php file an "echo" with an object with a "jumpURL" parameter with the desired url. Then include in your ajax call the parameter "dataType" with the value "json".